# How I can recover my windows data after almost installing ubuntu by mistake in the same drive

Tags: partitioning, ssd, data-recovery

I wanted to install ubuntu and I made the mistake of doing it on the same drive as windows. Before finishing the installation I got a message saying "Partition(s) 1, 4 on /dev/sdb have been written, but we have been unable to inform the kernel of the change". I pressed ignore and continue but then ubuntu could not be installed. I also could not get back to boot windows either. I would like to know if I can get the data I had on my ssd memory again.

Comment: Some that also use Windows say Windows tools work better as they may recovery full file names. Anything overwritten is gone, only way to recovery is from your backups. You can try testdisk and its deeper search and photorec. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery & 
http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk  & http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec & 
http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec_Step_By_Step

Answer (score 3):

It is unlikely to get restoration of data on a SSD.
Don't use the disk anymore for booting purpose as it may totally remove all your old data.

Use another drive that would act as your replica for doing the experimentations with multiple software tools. You want to be able to create a new disk dump if something goes bad.

Take the original disk out of the system, use another system or use this machine to set up a new system. Add this disk to the new system, and make a disk dump (on Linux this is the `dd` command) and put that dump on the new system.

Use restore tools like  [testdisk](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk)  to scan this file.  There are most tools, also specific for Windows that might be better to use for windows recovery.

Start making backups. If you consider your data important backups are mandatory. Incremental backups are easy to setup and do not take a lot of time to create after the 1st backup.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I do physical backups and there were some things I didn't save. At the moment I bought an adapter to be able to connect the SSD memory to another computer and with these applications I will try to recover something. I had understood that when ubuntu is installed it deletes the partitions so the memory organization disappears but the cells remain intact until they are overwritten, which I did not do because I could not install ubuntu. I would like to know why in the SSD memory would be almost impossible and in a common hard disk there is still the possibility?

Answer (score 2):

Now that the partitions have been written, the data is erased. The only way to recover it would be to use a data recovery software or service, although it may be difficult or potentially expensive to get back.

Comment: When you say it is difficult what do you mean? Because from what I've seen in forums a lot of things can get recover with relatively simple applications. is it because of the SSD memory?